# Listview onClickListener is not working in Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener, navigation-drawer

I am making a drawer having `ListView` in it. But surprisingly its not getting any `onClickListener` fired when I click on any list item.

**I have tried these things till now**

- Making a `ArrayAdapter` for `ListView` and get simply `list.onItemClickListener` and `list.onClickListener` too.
- A custom adapter with a implemented `OnClickListener`

Also for layouts even, I have tried these ways

- A layout with a parent `TextView`
- Layout with `RelativeLayout` as parent

Trying each case from above, I got nothing working till now. I guess that code is working well but might be some issue with layout, but trying everything I am still clueless.

Here is my current item layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:text="@string/app_label"
        android:paddingTop="14dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_label"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Custom Adapter

```
/****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

        /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    if (data.size() <= 0) {
        holder.text.setText("No Music Found!");

    } else {
        tempValues = null;
        tempValues = (ListModel) data.get(position);
        String txt = tempValues.getCompanyName().toString();
        holder.text.setText(txt);
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        // Set Values and listeners her

    }

    return vi;
}

/********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "rgrg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        HomeActivity sct = (HomeActivity) activity;
        sct.onDrawerItemClick(mPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // Default onClick
    Toast.makeText(activity, "rgrg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    Log.i("Long", "msg");
    return true;
}
```

And here is my activity

```
mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set the adapter for the list view
    setListData();
    DrawerAdapter adapter = new DrawerAdapter(this,
            CustomListViewValuesArr, getResources());
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setClickable(true);
```

Here is a listener in activity even

```
public void onDrawerItemClick(int mPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fgsg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I am **getting no Log and no Toast** which shows that nothing is clicked. After trying a lot, decided to get some help from you guys!

**EDIT**

I have did some further look up to see what happening and put a `button` in `listview`. In drawer the button is not even getting `onPressed` colors and hovers on pressing it. At all, the layout is very unresponsive or like not giving any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for giving suggestion for this issue. But I have found the cause for this abnormal behaviour. It is because of `RelativeLayout` (Outside Drawer Layout) defined in Activity's XML file (not item list XML). On removing that code, the click works as charm. :) Sorry for not including that code here..

You have to **set a fragment in FrameLayout** above drawer list view instead Relative Layout!

Comment: or you can just put listview below any of the layout, it should work!

Comment: For me there was a TestView after the RelativeView (Drawer). Worked after removing it.

Comment: There are two layouts allowed including drawer layout.

Answer (score 1):

In your `RelativeLayout` set `android:clickable="true"`. Or, a better approach would be to set an [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) on your `ListView`.

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO: do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: It does not help brother! See the Edit

Comment: Is that after adding `android:clickable="true"`? Add `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` to enable a color when pressed.

Comment: yeah I have added android:clickable true

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the on click listener on view, do it on relativelayout after initializing it

Comment: Your approach is very good bro but I still cant get it working.. my layout is freezed in drawer and not responding..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you list item click listener through `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(...)`

Comment: See Edit brother! and what you just said I have already tried.