# ListFragment.onListItemClick() not being called; possibly due to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment

I am perplexed as to why my `onListItemClick()` method is not being called.

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274231/listfragment-onlistitemclick-not-being-called) on the subject, and it mentions that any other components in the layout need to be set `android:focusable="false"`

However, here is my layout for that class. As you can see, it has no other components:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I checked in the layout for the parent activity, and it does have some other components, namely a drawer layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"> 
</FrameLayout>

<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can see that my ListFragment is being contained in the `FrameLayout` called `fragment_container`.

Could the `DrawerLayout` be preventing calls to my `onListItemClick()` method?
And, if so, how can I set is as unfocusable (it's a pretty huge layout...where should I put the `android:focusable="false"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue. I added a `FrameLayout` to contain my `Fragment`, but I see now that the `DrawerLayout` already contains within it a `FrameLayout` (called `content_frame`). So I just used `content_frame` instead of `fragment_container`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution - Set the `DrawerLayout` as base layout. You do not need to use a `RelativeLayout` outside of Drawer Layout as it is useless. This might be a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28525694/1460340)

Your layout should be

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!-- Recommended to use only one as both are match_parent -->
        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```